# Ubuntu 14.04 Periodical System Image Backup

Tags: live-usb, backup, restore

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a 32GB mSATA drive with a mechanical drive dedicated to Windows and a data partition. I've spent a lot of time setting up my install with things like Android Studio, Itellij, MySQL Workbench, etc. I would like to be able to backup my entire mSATA drive to my data partition on set intervals and I would like the output to be installable from a USB drive. All of the tools I've seen to make a bootable USB from a current install seem to have been depreciated, and I don't just want a backup of my home folder. I know I could do something like this with Clonezilla, but I want to schedule the backups to occur within the OS, I don't want to have to boot to a USB to make each backup. What are some tools I should look at?